# Add an arbitrary image above live camera feed using GPUIMage

Tags: ios, opengl-es, augmented-reality, gpuimage

I'm currently working on an augmented reality app, that's why I would like to add an image above the live video feed (GPUImageVideoCamera) AND be able to record the whole to an output file.

Get the video live preview, and recording is ok from now, but I can't manage to add the image on the screen the way it's recorded to the output file.

What's the best way to achieve this (I mean a GPUImage compliant way) ?

Comment: you may want to ask this question to the owner of GPUImage project - https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues

Comment: Yes good idea, I will post to this place too. Thx

Comment: @DeepThought did you find any thing for this.